# How to get 60Hz on a 4K Monitor using a 2018 Mac mini

Tags: thunderbolt, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport, 4k

I do a lot of work with music, and have two external 4K displays hooked up to my Mac mini. I’m using two LG 24UD58-B monitors, but I cannot get 60Hz out of them using an HDMI cable, which is then connected to a Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI Adapter. On LG’s website, it says 60Hz is only possible with a DisplayPort cable. I’m not sure which cable I would need in order to get 60 Hz on both of these monitors, so if anyone could recommend one, and which way it should be connected, I would really appreciate it. For example, would I need a Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort cable, with the DisplayPort end connected to the monitor, and the Thunderbolt 3 end connected to the Mac mini itself? Getting only 30Hz out of these monitors makes them feel really sluggish so I would definitely prefer to get the 60Hz out of them if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get [this USB-C (Thunderbolt) to DP cable](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07S7NTNHC/?tag=focusaperture-21).

I use it myself to run a 4k Dell monitor with 60hz, and it works flawlessly. You are right that most HDMI adapters don't support 4k with 60hz, although [the official specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_2.0) supports it theoretically from HDMI 2.0 onwards. Using the mentioned USB-C to DP cable solved this issue for me.